# Eclipse, how to remove default working sets?

Tags: eclipse, rad

When I opening a wizard [Select Working Set](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcworkset.htm) in a Eclipse (RAD), I have a list of predefined working sets. How can I delete unnecessary working sets? I tried remove by button available on the right side of this windows, but after a while a list has been restored. 
Thank you.

P.S. I use a RAD Version: 9.1, it's based on Eclipse 4.x version.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you want to limit number of projects displayed configure your own working set or uncheck unnecessary types in the `Selected working sets` list. I believe you cannot remove predefined working set

Comment: @Gas, exactly, I'd like to remove unnecessary predefined working sets.

Comment: Just uncheck them in the list and they want be displayed in the Project explorer.